# Using Cubature in python

Tags: python, numerical-methods

I am trying to calculate a seemingly simple integral. Here is the MMA code:

```
In[1]:= rect[x_] = If[x <= 0.5, 1, 0];

In[2]:= N[Integrate[Integrate[rect[(x^2 + y^2)^.5], {x, 0, 100.}], {y, 0., 100.}]]

Out[3]= 0.19635
```

However, when I do that with the [cubature](https://pypi.org/project/cubature/) package in Python, I cannot get anything reasonable for the integration limits over 13, and even for (-13,13) it lies. It really has to be something like +/- 10.

Here is the python code:

```py
import time
import numpy as np
from cubature import cubature

start = time.time()


def rect(r):
    return np.where(abs(r) <= 0.5, 1, 0)


def Wp(r1, r2):
    return rect((r1 ** 2 + r2 ** 2) ** 0.5)


def integrand_rectangle(x_array):
    return Wp(x_array[:, 0], x_array[:, 1])


# boundaries
a = 0.0
b_x = 100.0
xmin_t = [a, a]
xmax_t = [b_x, b_x]

val_t, err_t = cubature(integrand_rectangle, 2, 1, xmin_t, xmax_t, vectorized=True)
print(val_t)

end = time.time()

print(f"Runtime of the program is {end - start}")
```

I have tried to play with the number of interactions, relative and absolute error tolerances, nothing seems to cure this. Is there a solution? Why can't this well-tested package perform such a simple integration? Am I doing it wrong?

---

I have tried original C-cubature and **it works perfect and fast**! It is a problem of the python -- C interface! It is a bug!

Comment: Take a look at [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy/).

Comment: It looks like you want to integrate the area of a disk of radius `0.5`. You wouldn't do that using quadrature.

Comment: Original cubature package in C does it accurate and fast. It is only cubature wrapped for python lies. I am not good enough in python to spot where exactly the interface is corrupted. Also, I tried quadpy, nquad and mcint. First two are inaccurate and slow. Third one produces garbage. What is a good package to use then?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? The area of a something. Quadrature tools are not suitable for the task.

Comment: Can you try the C-cubature? It does it correctly. Suitable or not, the original C-package does it. The one with python - C interface fails. So this is not cubature itself. This is the interface.

Comment: To rephrase: the original C-package and the C-package-based python package produce different results, where C-package is right and python package is wrong. Python package uses C-package + interface. Hence, the problem is NOT the package, but the interface. I hope it makes better sense now.

Comment: On top of that "not-suitalbe"... Why, what are the limitations? Cubature is the adaptive integration procedure. Adaptive algorithms are one of the only options for this integral, since it is so delta-function-like. It is worth it to explain what you mean by that as well...

Comment: Let me try to do that in an actual reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to integrate a constant function over a domain (a disk of radius 1/2 in your case) to find out the area/volume of the domain. Although the problem can be formulated as an integral,

[image]

one would not typically do that with quadrature. The reason for this is that most quadrature methods (including  the one you use) are *Gaussian* quadrature methods, meaning that they will produce approximate results. The approximation is very good for smooth functions (i.e., polynomials of low degree). The function you have is not smooth at all, and even discontinuous at the boundary of the domain. That's why quadrature results will be inaccurate.

A more appropriate approach would be to try and triangulate the domain, using [one](https://github.com/nschloe/pygmsh) [of](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh) [the](https://github.com/inducer/meshpy/) [many](https://gmsh.info/) [available](https://github.com/nschloe/dmsh) [tools](https://bitbucket.org/fenics-project/mshr/).

[image]

After meshing, you can add the volumes of the triangles to get the domain volume.