# Integrate an indicator function in python with quad

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I am integrating an indicator function in python with [`scipy.integrate.quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html). However, the value I derived seems to be incorrect.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def indac(x, xc, rad):
    if xc - rad <= x <= xc + rad:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

phi = lambda ii, x: np.sin(ii * x)


xc = 0.1586663
rad = 0.01 * np.pi

result, _ = quad(lambda x: phi(1, x) * indac(x, xc, rad), 0., np.pi)
print(result)  # 0.0

a, b = xc - rad, xc + rad
result, _ = quad(lambda x: phi(1, x) * indac(x, xc, rad), a, b)
print(result)  # 0.009925887836572549
```

This gives me zero. However, the correct value can be acquired if I integrate from a to b as commented in the code.

It seems it is related to the quadrature method: similarly found in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64000768/using-cubature-in-python).

Any hints will be really appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is the function quad? [Is it this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html)?

Comment: Please include your imports when you post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `quad` does not evaluate the integrand at all possible points or even *many* points. As an adaptive quadrature method, it approximates the integral and estimates its own error, and (for efficiency) it terminates when its error estimate falls below the requested tolerances. Its error estimation strategy is excellent for many well-behaved functions, but yours does not satisfy its assumptions. After only 21 function evaluations that return exactly 0.0, its *error estimate* is zero, so it terminates with an integral of 0.0.

With the tighter interval, it sees the points at which the integrand is 1, so it returns the correct result.

Consider [`qmc_quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.qmc_quad.html#scipy.integrate.qmc_quad) which samples the space at as many quasi-random points as you please:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

def indac(x, xc, rad):
    return (xc - rad <= x) & (x <= xc + rad)

phi = lambda ii, x: np.sin(ii * x)

xc = 0.1586663
rad = 0.01 * np.pi

# The integrand callable needs to be vectorized to evaluate
# the integrand at `n_points` points in a single call. 
# Increase `n_points` for more accurate results.
res = integrate.qmc_quad(lambda x: phi(1, x) * indac(x, xc, rad), 
                         0., np.pi, n_points=10000)

print(res)
# QMCQuadResult(integral=0.009904273812591187, standard_error=1.5619537172522532e-05
```

Comment: Did you link to the wrong function? Please include your imports.

Comment: Oops, I was interrupted, and I accidentally copy-pasted the original code. Fixed now!

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation!